# File Upload Preferences not saving

Tags: settings, site-preferences

I am trying to make a change to the URL and Server Path of the File Upload Preferences section, but when I click "update" the page refreshes and the changes are gone. I don't have this issue anywhere but on the File Upload Preferences page, does anyone know what would be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be possible that in your config file that the upload preferences are being set via the config override. You will want to look for something along the lines of:

```
$config['upload_preferences'] = array(
    1 => array(                                                            // ID of upload destination
        'name'        => 'Staging Image Uploads',                          // Display name in control panel
        'server_path' => '/home/user/example.com/staging/images/uploads/', // Server path to upload directory
        'url'         => 'http://staging.example.com/images/uploads/'      // URL of upload directory
    )
);
```

You can find the full [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#upload-preferences) here

Comment: That was definitely it, thanks! Pretty new to ExpressionEngine and taking this project over for another developer so I'm still learning the ins and outs. Thanks again!